# vscode autoformats README.md file, coverting * to dashes

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

When I save my README.md file in vscode, it auto formats `*` to `-`.

FOr example:

```
* Cheese car
```

is converted to:

```
- Cheese car
```

How to prevent this?

Comment: do [an extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) and find out what extension is causing this. Then we can find out if there's a setting to change the behaviour. I'm way too lazy to go trying out random markdown extensions to figure out which one is causing this.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using prettier as your formatter, consider ignore the .md file in `.prettierignore`

```
*.md
```

Comment: who says they don't want formatting for their Markdown files? All I can see is that they don't want their list item characters to be converted.

Answer (score -2):

Use backslash (<kbd>\</kbd>) before every single asterisk (<kbd>*</kbd>). For example:

Input:

```
\* Cheese car
```

Output:

* Cheese car

Comment: who says they don't want to have a list item? All I see is that they don't want they list item characters to be converted.